# How to detect router switching in daisy chain network?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip

We have an embbeded Linux device product which supports the built-in network switch. The device has 2 ethernet ports. By using "daisy chain", 2 or more devices can be chained together. The Device2 is able to have networking as it's connected to Device1 which is connected to the router1.

```
      \    /        
    +---------+        +---------+
    | Router1 |--------| Device1 |
    +---------+     +--|         |
                    |  +---------+ 
                    |  
      \    /        |  +---------+
    +---------+     +--| Device2 |
    | Router2 |        |         |
    +---------+        +---------+
```

When we switch the router to another one for Device1, we have a way to detect the ethernet cable unplug/plug event in Device1. We trigger the IP address release and renew. This way, Device1 is able to update its IP address. For Device2, however, there is no way to detect the router switching. The subnet for router1 is 10.0.0.x. The subnet for router2 is 192.168.0.x.

By running "ip monitor" in Device2, there are some messages:

```
device# ip monitor
10.0.0.1 dev br0 lladdr b2:9b:68:0a:33:21 STALE
10.0.0.1 dev br0 lladdr b2:9b:68:0a:33:21 PROBE
10.0.0.1 dev br0  FAILED
10.0.0.1 dev br0  FAILED
```

How can I detect the router switching in this case for Device2? Is there something would change in "/sys/class/net/br0" folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are three basic approaches:

- unplug and replug Device2 as well
- shorten DHCP lease time (likely on Router1) to something you can live with (DHCP leases should be renewed after half the lease time is over)
- plug all devices into an intermediate switch and trigger a link down/up event there (reboot switch, deactivate & reactivate interfaces, ...)

Alternatively, if you can configure/program Device1 accordingly you can have it mirror the port 1 link status on port 2 (*if port 1 link comes up then flap port 2* - with good timing you could do it both ways).

Comment: Thanks @Zac67. For the first three solutions, it's likely that our customers need to take some actions. Those couldn't be the candidates. The last solution "mirror the port 1 link status on port 2", it sound like a good solution. Do you know how to do it in Ubuntu 18.04? Is there any examples?